# How to connect our smart contract that contains the fallback function to the imported smart contract?

Tags: fallback-function

i'm still confused, i'm importing a smart contract address on remix ethereum via ABI, i think for the fallback function it make sense to type the contract source code or use the ABI, i hope i am right about this. also my main question is ,,How do i add a fallback function/contract to an imported smart contract? i searched a lot but couldn't find it ,,when i import a smart contract verified on etherscan, how do i connect my smart contract that contains a fallback function?

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you mean.
You want to "Load contract from address" in Remix, so you can play around with it, right?
If this is the case, then you will need either the contract interface (if it implements one) or the contract source code or abi, so Remix knows how to interact with it. If you put the interface or contract source code in remix, then you select it and put the contract address in the "Load contract from address" box in remix, then click on "At address" and it should load. That loaded contract will be the one already running in Rinkebe.

Comment: what you tell, this is importing a smart contract, yes that's what I'm doing, My main question is, how do I add a fallback contract to an imported contract? Because I want to call the fallback function and interact with the smart contract

Comment: I still cannot understand what you mean. Could you add more details to your question? Code snippets, screenshots, etc.

Comment: OK, I'll try to explain better, I have done the smart contract import successfully, But I want to work with smart contract with fallback function how to do it?

Comment: Need to create a new fallback contract? To interact with a smart contract?

Comment: By fallback, do you mean the `fallback() external payable` function of a smart contract? The smart contract that you are importing does not have a `fallback() external payable` function and you wanted it to have one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138813/discussion-between-tomas-and-jeremy-then).

Answer (score 1):

To call a fallback function of a smart contract that is loaded in Remix, you just need to click on the "Transact" button:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Contract {

    fallback() external payable {
        // Do something or nothing and receive the eth sent to this contract
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}
```

Select some eth from the "Value" input box, and then click on "Transact" button at the bottom:

[image]

It's optional to specify any data.

You cannot call a payable function without sending some eth. When you call the `fallback() external payable` or `receive() external payable` function will accept the ether automatically. If you want to keep track in the smart contract of who has sent you some eth, you could create a `mapping(address => uint256) public balances` and save something like this: `balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;`. But either if you keep track of the deposits in the balances mapping, the smart contract's address itself is the one with the eth funds in the blockchain and only the smart contract can spend it (if it has logic to do so), sending eth to some other contract's address or any other address.

When you call a smart contract without specifying any data (no specific function to call), or the data does not match any function in the smart contract, then the `fallback() external` function will be called.
The `fallback() external` function must be `external`, but `payable` its optional for it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, When I call the  fallback function, will the extraction function be activated automatically?

Comment: What extraction function? You cannot call a `payable` function without sending some eth. When you call the `fallback() external payable` or `receive() external payable` function will accept the ether automatically. If you want to keep track in the smart contract of who has sent you some eth, you could create a `mapping(address => uint256) public balances` and save something like this: `balances[msg.sender] += msg.value`. But either if you keep track of the deposits in the `balances` mapping, the smart contract's address itself is the one with the eth funds in the blockchain.

Comment: When someone calls the fallback function, the fallback function can send the total funds In the caller's wallet?

Comment: No. You call the `fallback` function indicating the amount of eth you are sending to that function. The contract cannot spend your money on your behalf, you need to provide some eths to the contract and then the contract can do whatever it needs to do with that eth that is just received.